# How to change views in ViewPager Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter

I have a `ViewPager` with fragments in my activity, each page has a `textview`, I want to change the text of the `textview` from the `onCreate` method in the activity that contains the `viewpager`. How should I go about doing that?

below is the code that would return a null object exception:

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView textView;

public static MyFragment getInstance(){
    return new MyFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    return rootView;
}

public void setText(String text){
    textView.setText(text);
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MyFragment.getInstance();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Activity onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) adapter.getItem(0);
    fragment.setText("Altered");        // and this returns null pointer exception
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: That because your fragment still not `attached`, so `onCreateView` still not called and your `TextView` is null. See [fragment lifecycle](https://dzone.com/articles/visualization-android-activity) for more info.

Comment: So how should I go about changing the text or checking the status of the textview from main activity? (a.k.a. getting the view)

Comment: Please try this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Answer (score 1):

Most `FragmentPagerAdapter`s will have an `addFragment` method and will keep track various fragments that are added to it via an internal object:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

As it stands, your implementation of `getItem` returns a new instance of `MyFragment` every time it is called. As such, `MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) adapter.getItem(0);` is a new instance that will never be loaded into the `ViewPager`, will never be inflated, and hence has a null `textView` reference.

The other issue is that within the `onCreate` of your activity, the fragments have not yet been inflated, so the `textView` will be null unless you delay the call:

```
final MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fragment.setText("Altered");
    }
}, 100);
```

But really, why not just set it to the correct value when it is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Try This
Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView textView;
private String Text;
public MyFragment (String Text){
    this.Text=Text;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(Text); 
    return rootView;
}

}
```

Adapter :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new MyFragment("Altered");
}

@Override
    public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Activity onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```